# java filereader read at offset

Tags: java, offset, filereader

How do I use FileReader.read() to read a byte at a *specific offset*?

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
char[] tmp = null;
fr.read(tmp, 11, 1);
n = tmp.toString();
n = Integer.parseInt(n,16);
```

This code returns nullpointerexception although the file in 'path' is valid and not empty. What I intend to do here is to read the eleventh byte in that file.

reading lines from the file with BufferedReader.readLine() works well on the same file but I can't figure out how to get a specific number of bytes starting at a specific offset.

Comment: 1. don't use a `Reader` if it's to read bytes; 2. `tmp` is null, so of course you'll get an NPE.

Comment: Both InputStream and Reader have a skip(long) method...

Comment: Do you want to read the 11th **byte** or the 11th **character**? Bytes and characters are not the same.

Comment: sorry, character actually, I'm reading an old .DBF file containing just characters, no images or the like.

Comment: if I initialise the tmp array to a length of 100, that solves the nullpointerexception but I get [C@4d905742 as value for n, where I expected n to become 3, which is the actual value of the eleventh character. Also asking eg the 10th byte renders teh same value for n

Comment: You get [C@4d905742 because you are calling `toString` on a `char[]`. If you want to convert it to a string, do `new String(tmp)` instead of `tmp.toString()`.

Comment: in that case n becomes what seems to be an empty string? I tried to call x = fr.read() 11 times and in that case x gets the proper expected value? What is the difference? The number of characters returned as indicated by the return value of read()) is actually 1 as expected by the way.

Comment: @Jesper That's not correct. It should be new `String(tmp, count)` where `count` is the value returned by `read().`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `read(char[] buf, int offset, int length)`, the *offset* is offset in the buf array.
What you need is to skip *offset* characters.

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
int offset = 11;
fr.skip(11);
int c = fr.read();
```